# How do I produce Theorems and equations which are numbered by hand?

Tags: equations, numbering, theorems

I'd like to be able to write a LaTex document with numbered theorems and equations, but I would like *not* to have them numbered automatically, but rather put in by hand.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something like

```
\begin{thm-handnumbered}{3.1416}.  
The number $\pi$ is rational.
\end{thm-handnumbered}

As a consequence,
\begin{equation-handnumbered}{2.718}
e^{\pi i} = -1.003+0.014 i.
\end{equation-handnumbered}
```

and so produce "Theorem 3.1416", and an equation numbered "(2.718)".

(I can create a new theorem type for each numbered theorem (\newtheorem{thm-3.1416}...), but I've got a lot of them.  I can handcraft a "thm-handnumbered" command, but it looks ugly...)

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do this?

Comment: It's useful for refereeing papers, where one wants to quote a few equations with the original numbering.

Comment: It's also useful for students like me. I use a theorem environment for typing up exercises in my homework, and so I need the flexibility to manually fill in the appropriate exercise numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And here's a solution for hand-numbered theorems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[notefont=\bfseries,notebraces={}{},%
    headpunct={},postheadspace=1em]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,numbered=no,name=Theorem]{thm-hand}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm-hand}[3.1416]
Some text.
\end{thm-hand}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you!  (Took a few minutes to get thmtools installed correctly ... after you run "latex thmtools.ins", you need copy *all* the *.sty files into the texmf tree, not just the ones it tells you to copy ...)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer - but don't forget that frabjous provided the solution for equations. (There's this button for useful answers.)

Comment: I don't see a useful answer button ... or do you mean upvoting? (I don't have rep to do that yet.)

Comment: Yes, I meant upvoting. I forgot its reputation requirement.

Comment: This doesn't allow having a note after the theorem number as usual, right?

Answer (score 9):

For the second one, you could use `\tag` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\begin{equation}\tag{2.718}
e^{\pi i} = -1.003+0.014 i.
\end{equation}
```

For the first, I'd use `ntheorem` with a no-number style and then use the optional name:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newtheorem{handnum-theorem}{Theorem}
```

And in the body:

```
 \begin{handnum-theorem}[3.1416]
     This result is interesting.
 \end{handnum-theorem}
```

See the ntheorem documentation for more info.

Comment: Good point!  That'll handle equations.  So what about theorems?

Comment: I added to the answer later; but lockstep's answer may be better. Haven't tried it.

Comment: The main difference to your answer is that I avoid braces around the "manual" number.